# Running OnTrigger() on Content_main crush

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

i got an OnTrigger that is created on content_main

```
public class ContainMain extends Activity implements OnTriggerListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SlideBar slideToUnLock = (SlideBar)findViewById(R.id.slideBar);
        slideToUnLock.setOnTriggerListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrigger() {
        Log.d("Teset", "Slide Trigged");
    }

}
```

when i run the app on content_main it display Log.d
when i run it in activity_main it crush and the error log said Null pointer

Comment: Could you add the ActivityMain code? Also please add the NullPointerException description

Comment: I didd't call anything inside the activity_main.xml or activity_main.java, should include anything in that is call in the content_main inside the activity_main? do i need to call anything inside activity_main from contain_main?

Comment: If i am not mistaken, contant_main is within activity_main correct? 
note: I used the drawer layout in android studio

Comment: Are you using an external library? Where is called onTrigger()? In what line the exception is thrown? What contains your activity_main layout?

Comment: Error:

06-09 12:09:46.730 2962-2962/com.dev E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.dev.SlideBar$OnTriggerListener.onTrigger()' on a null object reference 

   public interface OnTriggerListener {
        public void onTrigger();
    }